# IIS logging troubleshooting

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, log-files, troubleshooting

We've got an IIS server that hosts about a dozen small websites.  A couple of the websites do not log activity.  We've gone into the IIS Admin console and each website is configured to log daily into  Drive:\logs\w3svcXXXX\ where XXXX is the numberic site ID.   We've stopped/started the websites in question, and even restarted the IIS Service.  But we do not get any log files.  We've looking the the Server's Event Viewer, and there are no relevant events.

Configuration:  Windows 2K3 with IIS 6.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you double-check, if the **"Log visits" option** under the home directory tab is enabled?

Compare the NTFS permissions of the folder which work to the folders that don't work. Maybe there is a missing permission. But you should see some evidence in the Windows Server eventlog for that issue.

There is a Microsoft TechNet article which could help: [Troubleshooting Logging Problems (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/23ec8be2-649a-47b7-8d75-ffd937f16fe8.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: Dang,  that the "Log Visits" option was it.  I'd gone through all the logging options on the General Tab, but missed the check box on the home directory tab.  Thanks.